# Why are my PostgreSQL random numbers right-padded with zeroes?

Tags: postgresql, decimal, plpgsql

I have written a PostgreSQL function to generate a random number with (up to) 40 digits.

After running the function a couple of times, it seems that the generated numbers only have their leading (up to) 15 digits actually randomized (range 0-9). The following digits are all zero.

That was very unexpected to me. Is this due to a restriction that I am not aware of, e.g. in the DECIMAL type, or in the OS, or in the multiplication operation?

Sample output:

- 9690529912293880000000000000000000000000
- 3876745014239130000000000000000000000000
- 8298320658130730000000000000000000000000

Thanks

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_random()
  RETURNS DECIMAL(40) AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    r DECIMAL(40) := 0;
    pos INTEGER := NULL;
BEGIN

    FOR pos IN 1..40 LOOP
        r := r * 10 + FLOOR(random() * 10);
    END LOOP;

    RETURN r;
END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;

SELECT test_random();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`random` returns `double precision` which has a limited precision. `numeric + double precision` yields `double precision`. To avoid that cast it to numeric:

```
r := r * 10 + floor(random()::numeric * 10);
```